# WebElement getText() returning empty string even though element is visible

Tags: java, xpath, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having a hard time retrieving the text of an element, for some reason WebDriver can find the element but it can't retrieve the text, I'm suspecting because for some reason the element is not visible to WebDriver, I'll get to that in a moment.

Here's a snippet of the HTML:

```
<td id="x-auto-4169" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-badCalls " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
    <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-badCalls" unselectable="on">0</div>
</td>
```

The Xpath to get to this is

```
String valueXpath = "((//div[@id=\"QosDashpardPanelBottom\"]//div[@id=\"CollectorQoSPerformanceMetricsgrid\"]//div[contains(@class, \"x-grid3-row  x-unselectable-single\")])[" + j + "]//div)[" + i + "]";
WebElement value = driver.findElement(By.xpath(valueXpath));
```

Where 'j' is the row number and 'i' is the column number respectively in a table/grid. I know that Selenium can find the element because I can do

```
WebElement class = driver.findElement(By.xpath(fullXpath));
String classAttr = arg.getAttribute("class");
```

and I return

```
x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-badCalls
```

but when I try

```
String cellValue = value.getText();
System.out.println(cellValue);
```

I get an empty string. I'm staring at my computer screen and I can see the value, it's visible, I know Selenium finds the element but I can't retrieve the text. Interestingly someone suggested to first click on the value then try to getText() so when I tried to click I got the exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

So I'm wondering if I'm not able to retrieve the text value because it's not visible? However if that's the case it seems strange that I can retrieve things like class attribute, tags, etc but not the text value.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<body class=" ext-gecko ext-windows" onload="processLoaders();">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="topNavDiv" style="height: 90px">
<div id="bodyContentOuter" style="width: 1280px; height: 587px;">
    <div id="bodyContentInner">
        <script src="RLT/RLT.nocache.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <script defer="defer">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        <div id="rtcpMain" class=" x-component x-border-layout-ct" style="width: 1280px; height: 587px;">
            <div id="rtcpMainWest" class=" x-panel x-component x-border-panel" style="left: 5px; top: 5px; width: 225px;">
            <div id="x-auto-2" class=" x-tab-panel x-component x-border-panel" tabindex="0" hidefocus="true" style="left: 235px; top: 5px; width: 1040px;">
                <div class="x-tab-panel-header x-unselectable" style="width: 1038px;" unselectable="on">
                <div class="tone-rtcp-tabbed-content-panel" style="width: 1040px; height: 550px;">
                    <div id="x-auto-10" class=" x-component" style="overflow: auto; width: 1040px; height: 550px;">
                        <div id="QosDashboardPanel0" class=" x-panel x-component" style="width: 1040px;">
                            <div id="x-auto-13" class=" x-small-editor x-panel-header x-component x-hide-display" role="presentation">
                            <div id="rtcpDPBWrap" class="x-panel-bwrap" role="presentation" style="overflow: visible;">
                                <div class="x-panel-tbar x-panel-tbar-noheader" role="presentation" style="width: 1040px;">
                                <div id="rtcpDPBody" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-border-layout-ct" role="presentation" style="width: 1038px; height: 700px;">
                                    <div id="QosDashboardPanelTop" class=" x-component x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1038px; height: 400px;">
                                    <div id="QosDashpardPanelBottom" class=" x-component x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" style="left: 1px; top: 401px; width: 1036px; height: 298px;">
                                        <div id="QosDashpardPanel_pqosChartsLC" class=" x-component x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct x-hide-display" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1036px; height: 400px;">
                                        <div id="QosDashpardPanel_metricsTablesLC" class=" x-component x-border-panel x-border-layout-ct" style="left: 1px; top: 1px; width: 1034px; height: 296px;">
                                            <div id="CollectorMetrics_toneletWrapper" class=" x-panel x-component x-border-panel" style="left: 1px; top: 1px; width: 330px;">
                                                <div id="x-auto-99" class=" x-small-editor x-panel-header x-component x-hide-display" role="presentation">
                                                <div class="x-panel-bwrap" role="presentation">
                                                    <div class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader" role="presentation" style="width: 328px; height: 292px;">
                                                        <div id="CollectorMetrics" class=" x-panel x-component" style="width: 328px;">
                                                            <div id="x-auto-109" class=" x-small-editor x-panel-header x-component x-unselectable" role="presentation" unselectable="on">
                                                            <div class="x-panel-bwrap" role="presentation">
                                                                <div class="x-panel-body" role="presentation" style="width: 326px; height: 265px;">
                                                                    <div id="CollectorQoSPerformanceMetricsgrid" class=" x-grid-panel x-component" style="position: relative; width: 326px; height: 265px;" tabindex="0" hidefocus="true" unselectable="">
                                                                        <div class="x-grid3" role="presentation" style="width: 326px; height: 265px;">
                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-viewport" role="presentation">
                                                                                <div class="x-grid3-header" role="presentation">
                                                                                <div class="x-grid3-scroller" role="presentation" style="width: 326px; height: 243px;">
                                                                                    <div class="x-grid3-body" role="presentation">
                                                                                        <div id="CollectorQoSPerformanceMetricsgrid_x-auto-633" class="x-grid3-row x-unselectable-single x-grid3-row-selected x-grid3-highlightrow " style="width:510px;">
                                                                                            <table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:510px;" role="presentation">
                                                                                                <tbody role="presentation">
                                                                                                    <tr role="presentation">
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-634" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-name x-grid-cell-first " style="width:148px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-name" unselectable="on">
                                                                                                                <u>Lync</u>
                                                                                                            </div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-635" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-badCalls " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-badCalls" unselectable="on">36</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-636" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-totalCalls " style="width:58px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-totalCalls" unselectable="on">120</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-637" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgLatency " style="width:73px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgLatency" unselectable="on">223</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-638" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgLoss " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgLoss" unselectable="on">0.80</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-639" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgJitter " style="width:58px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgJitter" unselectable="on">29</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                        <td id="x-auto-640" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgMOS x-grid3-cell-last " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                            <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgMOS" unselectable="on">3.86</div>
                                                                                                        </td>
                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                </tbody>
                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                        <div id="CollectorQoSPerformanceMetricsgrid_x-auto-641" class="x-grid3-row x-unselectable-single " style="width:510px;">
                                                                                            <table class="x-grid3-row-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:510px;" role="presentation">
                                                                                                <tbody role="presentation">
                                                                                                    <tr role="presentation">
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-642" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-name x-grid-cell-first " style="width:148px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-name" unselectable="on">
                                                                                                            <u>CUCM-Publisher</u>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-643" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-badCalls " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-badCalls" unselectable="on">3</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-644" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-totalCalls " style="width:58px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-totalCalls" unselectable="on">52</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-645" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgLatency " style="width:73px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgLatency" unselectable="on">190</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-646" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgLoss " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgLoss" unselectable="on">0.79</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-647" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgJitter " style="width:58px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgJitter" unselectable="on">31</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    <td id="x-auto-648" class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-avgMOS x-grid3-cell-last " style="width:53px;" role="gridcell">
                                                                                                        <div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-avgMOS" unselectable="on">3.98</div>
                                                                                                    </td>
                                                                                                    </tr>
                                                                                                </tbody>
                                                                                            </table>
                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                    </div>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that getElement returns the first matching element on the page.  Is there a possibility that you're getting an earlier match that is not visible?

Comment: @Aurand If I take that exact Xpath from valueXpath, properly substitute for i and j of course, and try it with firebug it works perfectly and I get the expected element. Is there any reason to believe getElement would get different results?

Comment: I think your `xpath` may be wrong. Just check it twice. Otherwise post your full HTMl code.

Comment: Inside **div[@class='x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-badCalls']** I couldn't find any child with tag div

I think thats why it is throwing exception..try with by removing last div tag from xpath

Comment: @Manigandan I checked and double checked my Xpath I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. I posted the full Html that's relevant, hopefully you can point me in the right direction.

Comment: @Santoshsarma I don't look for child nodes in the class you pointed out, if you look at my valueXpath variable I select a particular row in (@class, \"x-grid3-row  x-unselectable-single\") then from that row i select a div[i] which would be in the td branch

Comment: Again, too much code :). What Selenium version and browser are you testing on? It's possible that the content is generated after the load of the page - is is possible that your text is not yet present when checking? Try waiting for it a second or two. If nothing helps, I'll post a JS workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much (much) troubleshooting it turned out that I had a slight mistake on my Xpath. From my html

```
<div id="QosDashboardPanel0" ...
```

I was not accounting for multiple tabs. In my AUT I was opening a new tab, not a new browser tab but a tab in the application itself, and the whole Hmtl would remain the same except the snippet above would change to

```
<div id="QosDashboardPanel1" ...
```

I was assuming that the ID wouldn't change, well lesson learned! This is why I was running into the 'not able to click an invisible element', the element was in fact there but it was hidden behind my active tab.

Not much of a solution but I hope if someone is running into something similar this at least points them in the correct direction or makes a bell go off.